# Cannot Add Value From Web App To Existing Google Sheet Row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hey I am trying to add more values (from a submit form) to a specified existing row. But I got Console error:

> Uncaught  at processPk1

Here's my .html code:

```
onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)         //got this onsubmit in my form

<script>
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.processPk1(formObject);
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
</script>
```

Here's my .gs code:

```
function processPk1(formObject) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString(); });
var position = codeList.indexOf(formObject.code);    //this is to find the specified existing row position

ws.getRange(position,13).setValue(formObject.pdca);
ws.getRange(position,15).setValue(formObject.teamwork);
ws.getRange(position,17).setValue(formObject.strive);
ws.getRange(position,19).setValue(formObject.cnc);
}
```

Your response would be really appreciated. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to do is user could submit a "code" that exist in the Google Sheet, if it found then user could add the "formObject.pdca, formObject.teamwork, etc" on the same row as the "code".

Here's my sample spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NboiL7aIkUFq267t3yhy9hLRGrdbHI2jAlrIq54SvM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Modification points:

- In your script, when the value of `formObject.code` is not existing in the column "A" in "Sheet1", `position` is `-1`. By this, an error occurs. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- Also, when the same value for the column "A" is given, other values are not the same row of the value of column "A". From your script, I thought that you might want to put the same rows with the value of column "A".

When above points are reflected to your script, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

From:

```
ws.getRange(position,13).setValue(formObject.pdca);
ws.getRange(position,15).setValue(formObject.teamwork);
ws.getRange(position,17).setValue(formObject.strive);
ws.getRange(position,19).setValue(formObject.cnc);
```

To:

```
if (position > -1) {
  position += 2;
} else {
  position = ws.getLastRow() + 1;
  ws.getRange(position,1).setValue(formObject.code);
}
ws.getRange(position,13).setValue(formObject.pdca);
ws.getRange(position,15).setValue(formObject.teamwork);
ws.getRange(position,17).setValue(formObject.strive);
ws.getRange(position,19).setValue(formObject.cnc);
```

- In this modification, when `formObject.code` is not existing in the column "A", the values are appended to the sheet.

#### HTML and Javascript side:

`google.script.run` is run with the asynchronous process. So the following modification might be suitable.

From:

```
google.script.run.processPk1(formObject);
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => document.getElementById("myForm").reset()).processPk1(formObject);
```

### Note:

- **When you use Web Apps as the URL of `exec` and modified the script, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

### References:

- [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [getRange(row, column)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

### Added:

If you want to update the rows only when `formObject.code` is found at the column "A", how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

From:

```
ws.getRange(position,13).setValue(formObject.pdca);
ws.getRange(position,15).setValue(formObject.teamwork);
ws.getRange(position,17).setValue(formObject.strive);
ws.getRange(position,19).setValue(formObject.cnc);
```

To:

```
if (position > -1) {
  position += 2;
  ws.getRange(position,13).setValue(formObject.pdca);
  ws.getRange(position,15).setValue(formObject.teamwork);
  ws.getRange(position,17).setValue(formObject.strive);
  ws.getRange(position,19).setValue(formObject.cnc);
}
```

- By this modificction, when `formObject.code` is NOT found at the column "A", the script do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the modification, but it append the submitted value to a new row. What I'm trying to do is user could submit a "code" that exist in the Google Sheet, if it found then user could add "formObject.pdca, formObject.teamwork, etc" on the same row as the "code". Sorry if my question wasn't clear, I will update the question :)

Comment: @Ray Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, it is considered that `formObject.code` is not found in the column "A" of "Sheet1". And, when `formObject.code` is found in the column "A", the other values are put to the same row of `formObject.code`. Unfortunately, although I'm not sure about your whole script in your question, if my guess for your whole script was not the direction you expect, I apologize. For example, when you can provide the sample Spreadsheet including my proposal script, I can confirm the same issue with you.

Comment: Would it be better and saved time if i share my spreadsheet sample? If it does then I could provide it :)

Comment: @Ray Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor skill. As one more modification, I added it. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, at that time, in order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue?

Comment: I appreciate your time responding my question. Here I provide my spreadsheet for you to see the full code :) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NboiL7aIkUFq267t3yhy9hLRGrdbHI2jAlrIq54SvM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ray Thank you for replying and providing the sample. I have a question. When you tested my additional modified script, can I ask you about the result of it?

Comment: It didn't add anything which probably the position of "code" is not found even tho it exist in my Google Sheet

Comment: @Ray When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I could notice that in your script, `formObject.code` is used. But your HTML uses `codeInput`. This is the reason of your current issue. So please modify `var position = codeList.indexOf(formObject.code)` to `var position = codeList.indexOf(formObject.codeInput)`, and test it again. At that time, when you use Web Apps as the URL of `exec` and modified the script, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: ahh yeah I didn't realize it haha my bad.. Now it works like a charm! Really really thank you for your time and your help!

Comment: @Ray Thank you for replying and cooperating for confirming the issue. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.